# How to fill generated table with random values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I want to make application teamaker, choose how many players and teams you need, then click button and application will generate a table with random values with a range from Player 1 - Value of input PlayersNum. My biggest problem is table is filling but columns have the same values. What should I do?

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="content__header">Let's create some teams!</h1>

        <form action="#" class="form">
            <label for="playersNum">
                Number of players <input type="number" id="playersNum" class="form__input">
            </label>

            <label for="teamsNum">
                Number of teams <input type="number" id="teamsNum" class="form__input">
            </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Draw teams" class="form__submit">
        </form>
</div>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
const form = document.querySelector(".form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        let teamsNum = document.getElementById("teamsNum").value;
            let playersNum = document.getElementById("playersNum").value;

        if(playersNum %teamsNum == 0){
            const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
            const tbl = document.createElement("table");
            const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

            for (let i = 0; i < playersNum/teamsNum; i++) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");

            for (let j = 0; j < teamsNum; j++) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * playersNum + 1);
                let cellText = document.createTextNode("Player " + random);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
            }

            tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
            wrapper.appendChild(tbl);
            tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
            tbl.style.margin = "20px auto";
            tbl.style.width = "50%";
            tbl.style.textAlign = "center";

        } else alert("Teams must have the same number of players!");
});
```

});

[Repeating values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLI2m.jpg)

As you can see on the picture above, values are repeating. How to make every values without repeats in range from Player 1 to value which we have written in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

HTML

```
<center>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
             <h1>Welcome</h1> 
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <table border="1" id="lotto">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell00">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell01">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell02">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="red" id="cell03">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell11">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell12">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="red" id="cell13">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell20">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell21">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell22">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="red" id="cell23">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell30">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell31">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="normal" id="cell32">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="red" id="cell33">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Re-generate Numbers" />
</center>
```

JavaScript

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', UpdateTable);


// Set the max length of random number 
// and the max length
var maxLength = 4;

// Returns a random number
function CreateLottoValues() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
}

//create table
function UpdateTable() {

    for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
            tmp = 'cell' + i + j;
            document.getElementById(tmp).innerHTML = CreateLottoValues();
        }
    }
}

UpdateTable();
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/g6YTd/1/)

Comment: It will be fine, but I'm looking for code in which I can choose how many columns and rows my table will have. I can choose number of rows, columns then generate table with random values without repeats.